# How to take the derivative of $x_{ab} = \sum_{i=1}^{c} A_{ia}B_{ib}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I have an equation of

$$x_{ab} = \sum_{i=1}^{c} A_{ia}B_{ib}$$

Where $A \in \mathbb R^{c \times a}, B \in \mathbb R^{c \times b}$.

How to compute the derivative ?

$$\frac{\partial x_{ab}}{\partial A_{ia}} $$

And is it able to calculate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial A} $ wihout index? thanks a lot

Comment: It is trivial to show $\frac{\partial x_{ab}}{\partial A_{ia}}=B_{ib}$. I do not know what the last differentiation mean

Comment: @Andrei, thanks. I try to summary $\frac{\partial x}{\partial A} $ in matrix form. If take derivate with respect to all index.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then its a tensor

Comment: How about, we summary over matrix A. e.g., $\frac{\partial x_{ab}}{\partial A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index notation it is straightforward to calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
X_{jk} &= A_{ij}B_{ik} \cr
dX_{jk} &= dA_{ij}B_{ik} \cr
\frac{\partial X_{jk}}{\partial A_{mp}}
 &= \bigg(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mp}}\bigg)\,B_{ik}
 = \big(\delta_{im}\delta_{jp}\big)\,B_{ik}
 = \delta_{jp} B_{mk} \cr
}$$
Since four indices are involved, you cannot write this in conventional matrix-vector notation.

To use matrix-vector notation, you must vectorize (aka flatten) the equation like so
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(X) &= {\rm vec}(A^TB) = (B^T\otimes I_a)K\,{\rm vec}(A) \cr
\frac{\partial{\,\rm vec}(X)}{\partial{\,\rm vec}(A)} &= (B^T\otimes I_a)K \cr
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the vec-operation.